# Can someone give me a PK insert sample?

Tags: sqlite

So I'm making things complicated ...I think. A primary key basically is to make the row unique. Is that correct? Anyone want to show me an insert statement with the values for PK?

Answer (score 1):

The [SQLite documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html) says:

> On an INSERT, if the ROWID or INTEGER PRIMARY KEY column is not
>   explicitly given a value, then it will be filled automatically with an
>   unused integer, usually one more than the largest ROWID currently in
>   use. This is true regardless of whether or not the AUTOINCREMENT
>   keyword is used.

So, on a table like

```
CREATE TABLE test(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, descr TEXT);
```

an insert with a valid id could be

```
INSERT INTO test(descr) VALUES('this is a test');
```

Answer (score 0):

A primary key, also called a primary keyword, is a key in a relational database that is unique for each record. It is a unique identifier, such as a driver license number, telephone number (including area code), or vehicle identification number (VIN). A relational database must always have one and only one primary key.

if you are using CREATE TABLE, if you are creating the primary key on a single field, you can use:

CREATE TABLE mytable (
field1 TEXT,
field2 INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
field3 BLOB,
);

Reference more at: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html & http://sqlite.org/faq.html#q11